# Check IP in SQL Server database using php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want a query to check if the user IP is already in database, and if it is, to not allow that user to make a new account.

Here's Register.php, if you want, I will post it all

```
<!-- Body Start -->
                    <div id="body">
                    <?php
                    if(!$login)
                    {
                        $form = true;

                        if(isset($_POST['userbox']))
                        {
                            $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                            $user = $_POST['userbox'];
                            $mail = $_POST['email'];
                            $pw = $_POST['password'];
                            $pw2 = $_POST['password2'];

                            //require_once('includes/recaptchalib.php');
                            //$resp = recaptcha_check_answer (CMS_PRKEY,
                               // $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                               // $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                //$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

                            $user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
                            $mail = mysql_real_escape_string($mail);

                            if(check_mail($mail) && $pw == $pw2 && check_name($user) && strlen($user) < 21 && strlen($user) > 5)
                            {



                                $sql0 = "SELECT szUserID FROM TGLOBAL_GSP.dbo.TACCOUNT WHERE szUserID = '".$user."'";
                                $q0 = odbc_exec($ms_con, $sql0);
                                $nFree = odbc_num_rows($q0);
                                if($nFree == 0)
                                {



                                    $sql0 = "SELECT MAX(dwUserID) AS Result FROM TGLOBAL_GSP.dbo.TACCOUNT";
                                    $q0 = odbc_exec($ms_con, $sql0);
                                    $count0 = odbc_fetch_array($q0);
                                    $count = $count0['Result'];
                                    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


                                    $sql = "INSERT INTO TGLOBAL_GSP.dbo.TACCOUNT(szUserID, szPasswd, bCheck, dFirstLogin, szMail, szLastLoginIp)
                                    VALUES('".$user."','".$pw."', '1', {ts'".$date."'},'".$mail."','".$user_ip."')";
                                    $stmt = odbc_prepare($ms_con, $sql);
                                    odbc_execute($stmt, array($count + 1, $user, $pw, $mail));


                                    echo '<p>Dein Account wurde erfolgreich erstellt! Du kannst dich nun einloggen.<br /><a href="./login.php">&raquo; Zum Login</a></p>';

                                    $form = false;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $error = 'Der Benutzername ist bereits vergeben!';
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $error = 'Das Passwort, die eMail-Adresse oder der Benutzername waren nicht korrekt!';
                            }
                        }

                        if($form)
                        {
                            echo '<h4>Register</h4>';
                            echo'
                            <form action="register.php" method="post">
                            <label>Name <small><em>(required)</em></small></label>
                            <input type="text" name="userbox" id="userbox" />
                            <label>eMail-Adresse <small><em>(required)</em></small></label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                            <label>Passwort <small><em>(required)</em></small></label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
                            <label>Password wiederholen <small><em>(required)</em></small></label>
                            <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" /><br /><br />';
                            //require_once('includes/recaptchalib.php');
                            //echo recaptcha_get_html(CMS_PUKEY);
                            echo '<br /><input type="submit" value="Account anlegen" class="read_more2" />
                            </form>';

                            if(isset($error))
                            {
                                echo '<br /><p>'.$error.'</p>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<p>Du kannst keinen Account erstellen, da du eingeloggt bist!<br /><a href="./index.php">&raquo; Zur&uuml;ck zur Startseite</a></p>';
                    }



                    ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Body end -->
```

Comment: So what is the question?  IPs cannot be used uniquely identify people.

Comment: This is a querry that i used on another register script, but on this script must be modified and i don't know exactly how

Comment: // Check if user_ip already exists in the database.
 $sql = "SELECT szLastLoginIP FROM TGLOBAL_GSP.dbo.TACCOUNT WHERE szLastLoginIP = ?";
 $stmt = odbc_prepare($GLOBALS['dbConn'],$sql);
 $args = array($user_ip);
 if(!odbc_execute($stmt,$args)){
  $errors[] = 'Failed to determine if this IP already exists in the database.';
  }elseif($row = odbc_fetch_array($stmt)){
   $errors[] = 'You are not allowed to have more than one account on this server. Please contact the Administrator!';
  }

Comment: rather than using the ip address ( which can change daily or be shared by numerous users ) perhaps use javascript to create a fairly unique fingerprint and check that fingerprint. ( search google for canvas fingerprinting )

Comment: Yeah, but i'm not so good in scripting, maybe latter when i will learn more. For now i wat that query to adapt to my register script